# Javascript how can i make slideshow only for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to do slideshow but when i add js its broke the pc version
and i want this 3 pic stay there and when i look at mobile version this 3 pics slideshowing how can i do this i couldnt find ayn resource

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6kCA.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give your images a class and apply your CSS to them instead of the div you have put them inside.

*or*

Instead of having the image in your HTML you could use background-image in your CSS

with this css your image will resize with the container

```css
.container{
  background-color:blue;
  width:100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.slot-one{
  background-color:grey;
  height: 50%;
  width:50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/e4KRzS--UsuixA2G8TOCwJ-O024=/1400x1050/filters:format(png)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/6839749/pokemon.0.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="slot-one">
    <h1> TEXT</h1>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem correctly, but I don't think there will be a cover problem with display flex and width 100%.

If I understood wrong, please give to us more details about your problem.

```css
.container{
width: 100%;
display: flex;
}
.container div {
border:1px solid red;
}
.container div img{
width: 100%;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div><img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/e4KRzS--UsuixA2G8TOCwJ-O024=/1400x1050/filters:format(png)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/6839749/pokemon.0.png" alt=""></div>
<div><img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/e4KRzS--UsuixA2G8TOCwJ-O024=/1400x1050/filters:format(png)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/6839749/pokemon.0.png" alt=""></div>
<div><img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/e4KRzS--UsuixA2G8TOCwJ-O024=/1400x1050/filters:format(png)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/6839749/pokemon.0.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```